# Which Test should i run to check if there is any difference between variables?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, group-differences

I am analyzing one data set that contains 200 observations and contains information about two types or murders. It has 49 variables and I am interested in checking whether there is any difference between the variables or not based on the type of the murders. So basically, I have 125 observations that are classified as murder type 1 and 75 observations that are classified as murder type 2, and I want to see if there is any difference between the values of the 49 variables of these groups
I was thinking about running t-test or ANOVA, but I am not sure which test should i run to solve this problem

Thanks!

Comment: P.S: Most of the variables are categorical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a series of pairwise comparison tests for each variable between the two groups and use a correction for alpha inflation. For continuous variables, you could use a t-test or Mann-Whitney U-test, and for categorical variables, you could use a chi-square test for independence.

Common corrections include the Benjamini-Hochberg adjustment and Scheffe's correction.